# oracle jet amount format based on locale

Tags: javascript, oracle-jet

I need to format amounts as per the pattern '##,###.00' in my application which uses oracle jet. As per the oracle jet documentation, it provides option style 'Currency' in built in number Converter and can be used as below,

```
var options= {
                style: 'currency',
                currency: 'EUR',
                useGrouping: true,
                currencyDisplay: 'code',
                pattern:'#,###.## ¤'
            }
let converter = oj.Validation.converterFactory("number").createConverter(options);
let value = converter.format("2323.343");
```

But, this will format amount based on the current locale value in

```
oj.config.getLocale()
```

So, if locale is set to any country where ',' is used as decimal separator, this converter will return something like 2.323,34 EUR. My requirement is to get same format for amount irrespective of the locale value. Oracle jet documentation says nothing about any option to override this. Anyway I can do this using oracle jet only ??

Comment: Can you explain your question with an example ? or create a fiddle ?

Comment: Oracle jet documetation site is more than enough, I think. It contain examples also: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=converters&demo=numberConverter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the option hidden on JSDoc page of oj IntlNumberConverter. Ojet provides an option called **separators** to specify decimal and grouping separators.